# When did usage of the word polynomial become standard?

Tags: algebra

When did (cognates of) the word *polynomial* become standard in mathematical writing for expressions like $x^2 -x + 1$ and $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$?

In the 3rd edition of an 1822 English translation by Rev. John Hewlett of a French edition of **Euler's** *Elements of Algebra*, **1770**, one does not see the word polynomial for such expressions---they are usually called "formulas".

**Legendre's** **1798** *Essai sur la Théorie des Nombres* uses the word *polynôme*. Various cognates of this word (e.g., Polynom, polynomial, etc.) appear regularly in publications from then till the present.

The title of **Gauss's** PhD Thesis of **1799** has the phrase *Omnem Functionem Algebraicam Rationalem Integram*, which translates into English as "all integral (whole) rational algebraic functions". Gauss continues using similar phrases in his famous *Disquitiones Arithmeticae* (**1801**).

Such a phrase appears in many German publications throughout the 19th century as *ganze rationale algebraische Funktion*, often shortened to *ganze rationale Funktion*, or even *ganze Funktion*. It was used by **Dedekind** in **1857**, by **Dedekind and Weber** in their **1882** paper giving an algebraic treatment of Riemann surfaces, and in **Weber's** influential *Lehrbuch der Algebra* (**1895**, **1896**).

**Dirichlet's 1840** paper on number theory uses the word *polynôme*.

**George Boole's** *Mathematical Analysis of Logic*, **1847**, uses simply *function* or *expression*.

**Joseph Serret's** *Cours d'algèbre supérieure*, **1849**, uses both *polynôme* and *fonction rationale entière*.

**George Chrystal's** *Algebra* of **1885** uses English translations of Gauss's terminology.

I did not find the word *Polynom* while browsing through **Hilbert's** Collected Works. He does use Gauss's wording in some of his publications.

Modern algebra was introduced, in the German language, by the trio of **E. Noether** (German), **E. Artin** (Austrian) and **B. van der Waerden** (Dutch). Noether was the oldest, van der Waerden the youngest.

**Noether** started out using Gauss's wording in **1908**, then used both wordings in two papers in **1915**, then just Gauss's wording in two more papers of **1915** and in one paper in **1916**. It seems that she permanently switched to *Polynom* in **1918**.

**Artin** started with a paper in **1924** using Gauss's terminology, but then switched to using *Polynom* in 4 papers of **1927** (two with **Schreier**).

**Van der Waerden** seems to have used only *Polynom*, starting in **1927**, and most importantly in his very influential two volumes (**1930**, **1931**) of *Moderne Algebra*.

So it seems that the abandonment of Gauss's terminology by the leading German language algebraists was taking hold near the end of WWI. Had the French been responsible for the modern algebra, then of course one would expect the terminology to be *polynôme*; but why did the German language leaders in algebra choose to go with *Polynom* instead of Gauss's terminology? Was it connected to the passing of the old guard,  **Weber** (1913) and **Dedekind** (1916)?

Comment: For such questions please see [Jeff Miller's website Earliest Known Uses of
Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html):"*POLYNOMIAL was used by François Viéta (1540-1603) (Cajori 1919, page 139). The word is found in English in 1674 in Arithmetic by Samuel Jeake (1623-1690): "Those knit together by both Signs are called... by some Multinomials, or Polynomials, that is, many named"*".

Comment: @Conifold please move that to an answer

Comment: See François Viète, [In Artem Analyticem Isagoge](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k108865t/f11.image.r=Fran%C3%A7ois+Vi%C3%A8te.langFR), page 6: "*polynomijs*".

Comment: From the cited sources one finds that Viete used "polynomial" as replacement for "multinomial" which was a recent extension from "binomial, trinomial" which all at that time indicated the number of terms in a sum, not the algebraic use. Around 1800 "polynomial coefficients" was used for what today are "multinomial (combinatorial) coefficients". That all can be found in the Cajori book. For the occurrence of "polynomial" as algebraic entity the question is the best answer I have seen. Note that german schools still use "ganzrationale Function" without any connection to historical sources.